# SCSS получение значений массива?

Tags: sass, scss

Погуглил документацию sass/scss, но внятных ответов на мои вопросы не нашел.

Допустим, имеется массив:

```
$arrayColors: (
        white,
        black,
        green,
        red,
        orange
);
```

**Вопросы 1:**

1.1. Как получить последнее значение массива?

Имеется цикл перебора массива:

```
@each $key, $color in $arrayColors {
      .color-#{$key}
      {
        color: $breakpoint;
      }
}
```

**Вопросы 2:**

2.1. Как начать перебор массива с конца?

2.2. Если начали перебор массива с конца, то как теперь получить первое значение массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Натолкнул на верное решение `@iiiBird`. Погуглив, задачи реализовал следующим образом:

**1.1. Как получить последнее значение массива?**

```
map_get($arrayColors, length($arrayColors));
```

**2.1. Как начать перебор массива с конца?**

```
@for $i from length($arrayColors) through 1 {
 color: nth($arrayColors, $i);
}
```

**2.2. Если начали перебор массива с конца, то как теперь получить первое значение массива?**

```
map_get($arrayColors, 1);
nth($arrayColors, 1);
```